# Sonarqube build for UWP-App failed

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, visual-studio-2017

I habe a TFS-Server-Build (TFS 2017) on a Build-Agent with VS 2017. The first Buildstep (Prepare the Sonarqube analysis) and the build of the solution works fine. But i have a error at "Complete the SonarQube analysis":

`2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]Possible causes:
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
2017-05-29T03:06:09.1933915Z ##[error]05:06:09.115  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1`

Can anyone help?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with TFS-Server-Build,, but the possible causes are mentioned.
Check the following [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) for more details on how to set it up properly

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error mentioned this stands for `SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects`

Even though you have installed MSBUILD 12 or above, you should make sure the Build agent is calling the right version.

And double check if the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner` and `MSBuild` is running from **the same working directory**.  At `.sonarqube/out` folder the *sonar-project.properties* is  getting created or not.